# Examples of interactive TreeMap for iPad

Tags: ipad

Does anybody know of any interactive [tree map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treemapping) examples for iPad ? I am not asking about libraries/APIs, etc. I am asking about actual applications.

Answer (score 1):

[TreemapKit @ GitHub](https://github.com/yatsu/treemapkit) is one that works ok ... The only one written for iOS as far as I know. It works on the iPhone and iPad, but it doesn't redraw and rescale correctly when you rotate the device. I can't figure out how to fix that and the author is too busy to revisit

But you want applications ... There aren't any as far as I've seen, and I've been looking. This is largely due to the absence of a good ObjC library, save for TreemapKit. It does come with a demo though.

Comment: I forked and fixed it for iPad.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any examples, but given that it's fairly hard to tap on an small area of a TreeMap I don't think it's feasible to use.

What are you exactly trying to do?